# Java works fine in Eclipse, but cannot run normally in Terminal

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04, JRE 1.6.0

In my zsh, even a simple `hello.java` cannot run normally.
It's ok when compiled it with `javac`, but then typed `java hello`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: hello.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: What package is HelloWorld.java in?

Comment: i believe it should be `java helloworld`

Comment: @Apurv hello.java. I edited the question

Comment: Great! 3 (similar) answers and one with 4 up votes and now you edited your question.

Comment: @Apurv Apologize for that...

Answer (score 4):

Your class name seems to be `helloworld` and you are trying to say `java hello`

(hence JVM tries to find a class named `hello` which doesnt exist)

please try `java -classpath . helloworld`

Comment: As i have mentioned, you need to add current directory to the classpath using `java -classpath .` and then you can try again

Answer (score 0):

The class name is `helloworld` and you are trying to say `java hello`. Check it once

Answer (score 0):

Try java helloworld. By default, Java will compile with the same name as the file.

so javac helloworld.java outputs helloworld.class, which is what you need to access to run the bytecode.